# Phrase that refers to all the events in a person's life?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that I think goes like "Life [Phrase]". It means something like "The whole sequence of events of a person's life"?

For example,

> College, then Marriage, then Kids, then [Phrase]

And I remember it being used as a news article title:

> "Modern Life [Phrase]-s are changing, girls are having kids before marriage, etc."

I don't think its "Life Schedule" or "Life Plan".

However, I don't think that the news article would say that the "Modern Life [Phrase]-s" are 'changing', but more that they are 'broken'.

It feels like a psychological term that means

> The plan that you have, of the events that you want in your life, and what order you want them to be in and how old you are at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I might actually have been thinking of Life Plan...

Either that, or **Life History**...

> In sociological and anthropological research, a life history is the overall picture of the informant's or interviewee's life. The purpose of the interview is to be able to describe what it is like to be this particular person, that is, the one being interviewed.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_history_%28sociology%29)

Answer (score 2):

[Course](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/course) is used for the time, events and vicissitudes that refer to  life:

> - development in a particular way; progress:
>
>   - the course of events in one's life
> - a continuous progression from one point to the next in time or space; onward movement:
>
>   - *the course of his life.*

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

I think "experiences" might be the right phrase. Perhaps "life experiences". There are many definitions of "experience" that would fit your requirements (particularly with "life" added), but the one I think is most useful is

> an event or occurrence that leaves an impression on someone.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/experience).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with **life stages** See [here, for instance](http://www.institute4learning.com/stages_of_life.php)

The concept goes back at least to the ancient Greeks, and the riddle of the Sphinx:

> What goes on four legs in the morning, two legs at noon, and three
>   legs in the evening?

To which Oedipus replied

> Man—who crawls on all fours as a baby, then walks on two feet as an
>   adult, and then uses a walking stick in old age.

Answer (score 1):

Is **life cycle** what you're looking for?

> life cycle: a series of stages, as childhood and middle age, that characterize the course of existence of an individual, group, or culture. ([**RH**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/life--cycle))
>
> *Life cycles are changing.* ([**Southern Governors**](http://www.southerngovernors.org/Portals/3/documents/PDF/2013%20Future%20of%20the%20South%20SGPB.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

Curriculum vitae would be perfect, but alas, it's taken.

I'd suggest the somewhat folksy "seasons of life", if that suits the tone you need.

Answer (score 0):

**"life style"** seems to fit.

"Life style in the American society has changed: girls are having kids before marriage."

> - A way of life or living of a person or group: an unconventional lifestyle; money needed to maintain one's lifestyle. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lifestyle)